# Remove unnecessary comma - sql query

Tags: sql, regex, concatenation, regexp-replace

```
select 
  (select 
   (SELECT listagg(z.errcd_abbr || ' - ' || z.errcd_80char || ' (C)', ', ') within group (order by z.errcd_abbr)
    FROM v_errcd z 
    WHERE z.parsetype_id = 'UTIL' AND z.errhdrdet_cd in ( 'ITEM' ) 
    AND 
    (imany_utility_pkg.bit_and(v.submitem_critical_errors, z.errcd_raw) = z.errcd_raw AND (not z.errcd_flg_obsolete='Y')))
    || ', ' ||
   (SELECT listagg(z.errcd_abbr || ' - ' || z.errcd_80char || ' (M)', ', ') within group (order by z.errcd_abbr)
    FROM v_errcd z 
    WHERE z.parsetype_id = 'UTIL' AND z.errhdrdet_cd in ( 'ITEM' ) 
    AND 
    (imany_utility_pkg.bit_and(v.submitem_cbmbo_errors, z.errcd_raw) = z.errcd_raw AND (not z.errcd_flg_obsolete='Y')))
    || ', ' ||
   (SELECT listagg(z.errcd_abbr || ' - ' || z.errcd_80char || ' (W)', ', ') within group (order by z.errcd_abbr)
    FROM v_errcd z 
    WHERE z.parsetype_id = 'UTIL' AND z.errhdrdet_cd in ( 'ITEM' ) 
    AND 
    (imany_utility_pkg.bit_and(v.SUBMITEM_WARNING_ERRORS, z.errcd_raw) = z.errcd_raw AND (not z.errcd_flg_obsolete='Y')))
    || ', ' ||
   (SELECT listagg(z.errcd_abbr || ' - ' || z.errcd_80char || ' (O)', ', ') within group (order by z.errcd_abbr)
    FROM v_errcd z 
    WHERE z.parsetype_id = 'UTIL' AND z.errhdrdet_cd in ( 'ITEM' ) 
    AND 
    (imany_utility_pkg.bit_and(v.SUBMITEM_OVERRIDDEN_ERRORS, z.errcd_raw) = z.errcd_raw AND (not z.errcd_flg_obsolete='Y')))
  FROM DUAL  
  ) errorCodes 
FROM
   v_submitem_error v;
```

I have the above query which concatenates error columns based on their severity using a comma in the below format. 
`ERROR_CODE - ERROR DESCRIPTION (SEVERITY)`
Error code can have severity one of the C,M,W,O. However, there is a possibility that for a particular row error with all severity does not exist. In those cases above query returns following output

```
UOB - Submitted UOM not base UOM (C), , BBI - Book of Business Invalid (W), UDI - User-defined date missing or invalid (W), 
, , BAI - Trading partner ANSI# invalid (W), PTI - Product ID type invalid/missing (W), 
, , BAI - Trading partner ANSI# invalid (W), FII - Formulary ID is Invalid (W), PTI - Product ID type invalid/missing (W), 
DDC - Different Division Associated with Contract (C), PAM - Product ID ANSI # invalid (C), , , 
, , BAI - Trading partner ANSI# invalid (W), PTI - Product ID type invalid/missing (W), 
UOB - Submitted UOM not base UOM (C), , , 
, SDG - Start date > end date (M), MPF - Multiple products found (W), 
, , BBI - Book of Business Invalid (W), MFF - Multiple Formularies Found (W), NFF - No Formulary Found (W), 
, SDG - Start date > end date (M), , 
, , BAI - Trading partner ANSI# invalid (W), PTI - Product ID type invalid/missing (W), 
, , CSI - Contract status is in process (W), CSS - Contract status is submitted (W), PTI - Product ID type invalid/missing (W), SDG - Start date > end date (O)
```

I want to use some string replacement technique which eliminates unnecessary comma.

Comment: How is this any different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59351599/sql-query-to-remove-unwanted-comma-while-doing-string-concatenation), which was closed for not being clear?

Comment: The earlier question did not have problematic rows. This question has some more details.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `case` to check if the error code is `null` before concatenating it, like so:

```
listagg(
    z.errcd_abbr 
        || case when z.errcd_80char is not null then ' - ' || z.errcd_80char end
        || ' (C)',
    ','
)
```